# Unexpected StrComp result when string is sent from golang app

Tags: go, vbscript

In my code below I've set up a `ReadString` which reads user input and passes it along in a `exec.Command`.

This works just fine, but when I try to compare the string with a hardcoded string in vbscript (in this case I'm comparing it to "hello") it always fails even when the user input is "hello" as well.

If I just run the vbscript through the command line like this however...

```
 cscript.exe script.vbs hello
```

...then the `StrComp` works as intended so I suspect that it's either a data type issue or there's some extra character that's passed along in the golang app.

Here's the **main.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Type something: ")
    text, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        args := []string{"./script.vbs", string(text)}
        exec.Command("cscript.exe", args...).Run()
    }
}
```

And here's the **script.vbs**

```
MsgBox(WScript.Arguments(0))

If StrComp(WScript.Arguments(0), "hello") = 0 Then
    MsgBox("it's the same")
Else
    MsgBox("It's not the same...")
End If
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with vbscript but isn't argument[0] gonna be equal to "script.vbs" rather than hello? You can try adding a print to see what the value is, since there is probably no problem with your StrCmp call. The string just isn't equal to hello.

Comment: @Ullaakut No, if you run the vbscript like this via cmd `cscript.exe script.vbs hello` and you're on windows you can see for yourself that the WScript.Arguments(0) is indeed "hello"

Comment: Can't you print the result byte per byte? I don't have a windows machine to try this on

Comment: @Ullaakut I'll see what I can do, might take a while,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with windows, line endings are "\r\n". I don't know whether ReadString() should remove the delimiter, but even then text will contain an invisible \r. Use strings.TrimSpace to be on the save side:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Type something: ")
    text, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Printf("0 got: %T %v %q\r\n", text, text, text)
    text = strings.TrimSpace(text)
    fmt.Printf("1 got: %T %v %q", text, text, text)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        args := []string{"./script.vbs", string(text)}
        exec.Command("cscript.exe", args...).Run()
    }
}
```

output (of main; use your imagination for the VBScript MsgBoxes):

```
main
Type something: hello
0 got: string hello
 "hello\r\n"
1 got: string hello "hello"
```